# -bash: laravel: command not found

Tags: php, linux, bash, laravel

I have installed the composer and move the composer.phar file to /usr/local/bin
 just follow the following step:

```
#curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Then I  edit my `~/.bash_profile` file as following:

```
export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin
```

and save the change and excute:

```
#source ~/.bash_profile
```

But, when I excute the laravel new test command, it returns an error:

> ```
> -bash: laravel: command not found
> ```

PS:
in `/usr/local/bin` directory have no laravel command just composer command exists.

Did I forgot something?

Comment: You forgot to require [laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/master). Do `composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, download the Laravel installer using Composer:

Command like this,

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

for more information [Click Here](http://laravel.com/docs/master)

Comment: Yeah, I have downloaded the Laravel installer before setting the environment variable with .bash_profile. But both laravel new and composer create-project commands can not be execute successful.